# I can't recover Sql data from combobox. Error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

By selecting an item in the combobox, I would like to retrieve the database row that has the same name selected by the combobox in one of the fields.

For example, if in the combobox there is Tokyo, Madrid, London, Paris (obtained from the "example" column of the database) and I select Tokyo, I would like the row that has the text "Tokyo" in the "example" column to be searched in the database table. Then print the row separately.

I get the error when I try and retrieve and print the data:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

While tweaking the code a bit and trying to fix it, I no longer get the error, but the variables are printed as `None, None, None, None.`

I don't need the function ad i don't need a button. I would simply like that by selecting the combobox, the variables are printed.

Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.config(bg="gray")
root.state("normal")
  
conn = sqlite3.connect('....')
cursor = conn.cursor() 

def view_combobox():
    cursor.execute('SELECT example FROM material LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2')
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor]    
    return values

example=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 21)
example.place(x=10, y=10)
example.set("Select")
example['value'] = view_combobox()
            
select_example__button3 = example.get()

#################################################
#PROBLEM IS HERE
if select_example__button3:

    cursor.execute('SELECT a, b, c, d FROM material WHERE example=?', (select_example__button3,))
    value = cursor.fetchone()

    print(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4])
```

Database

```
CREATE TABLE "material" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "a" INTEGER,
    "b" INTEGER,
    "c" INTEGER,
    "d" INTEGER,
    "example" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
```

NOTE: I have tested that if I insert the condition inside a function and then call the function with a button, I no longer receive the error and the variables are printed correctly. But it was just a test, I DON'T NEED THE FUNCTION, AND I DON'T NEED A BUTTON. I would simply like that by selecting the combobox, the variables are printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` is telling you that you're trying to use a subscript on a variable that has the value `None`.

In your case it is the `var` variable. It is `None` because you are calling `cursor.execute` about a millisecond after creating the combobox. The user won't have seen the combobox much less had a chance to pick a value from it. Therefore, the value is going to be what you set it a few statements prior to the empty string and thus, the SQL statement won't find any matches.

> I would simply like that by selecting the combobox, the variables are printed

To run a function when a combobox is selected you can bind to the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event. It might look something like this:

```
def select_example(event):
    selected_value = example.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT a, b, c, d FROM material WHERE example=?', (selected_value,))
    value = cursor.fetchone()
    if value:
        print(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4])

example.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select_example)
```

Comment: There are some small errors in your code, but they are definitely careless and typos :) I corrected. However your code does not solve the problem!!! I don't get errors, but nothing prints. The console remains empty. Why? How can this be solved? Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro: you'll need to verify that `selected_value` is what you think it sh ould be, and then verify that there really is something in the database with that value.

Comment: I verified. The value exists and is correct. I replaced your code with "current" with .get and now it works correctly. Why?

Comment: @DragomirCro: that was a bug in my code.

Comment: Thanks. Green tick and answer accepted as solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you `checked` the `value` return from `cursor.fetchone()`. If due to any reason if it returns `empty` `resultset` it returns `None`. So check the `value` obtained from `cursor.fetchone()` if it is not `None` then only print the `value` as

```
cursor.execute('SELECT a, b, c, d FROM material WHERE example=?', (select_example__button3,))
value = cursor.fetchone()
if value is not None:

    print(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4])
```

Comment: Your answer is very trivial and it didn't help me. It is useless to verify. I can't print "value" just because it is None. I don't need to check with the "if". Do you have a solution? Thank you

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me? I still haven't found a solution